# fabric.js - Cannot add 'text object' to canvas on button click (canvas that contains image)

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

So I have a fabric canvas. The canvas contains an image (uploaded by the user).
I'm also displaying multiple buttons and each of them has a title. When clicking on the button, I want to create a text object and append it to fabric canvas. I'm using React.js. I've created the function and the function is being called as well as the textObj however I'm not seeing the text added to the canvas. What am I missing here ?

Here is the code, notice 'handleAddFormParameter' function that is being passed to CanvasParameters component

```
const CanvasMain = () => {

  const [canvas, setCanvas] = React.useState("");
  const [doesCanvasHaveImg, setDoesCanvasHaveImg] = React.useState(null);
  const [imageDimensions, setImageDimensions] = React.useState(null);
  const [cardFont, setCardFont] = React.useState(null);

  const handleImageUpload = (e) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      const image = new Image();
      image.src = e.target.result;
      image.onload = function () {
        const img = new fabric.Image(image);
        setDoesCanvasHaveImg(true);
        setImageDimensions({ width: img.width, height: img.height });
        img.hasControls = false;
        img.hasBorders = false;
        img.lockMovementX = true;
        img.lockMovementY = true;
        img.hoverCursor = 'default';
        canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img).renderAll();
      };
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleAddFormParameterToCanvas = (formParameterText, visible = true) => {
    console.log(formParameterText);
    const textObj = new fabric.Text(formParameterText, {
      fontFamily: cardFont || 'Arial',
      fontSize: 16,
      fill: 'red',
      top: 0,
      left:0
    });
    canvas.add(textObj);
  }

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const initCanvas = () =>
      new fabric.Canvas("c", {
        height: 800,
        width: 800,
      });
    setCanvas(initCanvas());
  }, []);


  return (
    <main>
      <header>
        <h1>Fabric Image Test</h1>
        <br />
        <input
          type="file"
          name="myImage"
          accept="image/*"
          onChange={(e) => handleImageUpload(e)}
        />
        <button onClick={() => {
          if (canvas !== '') {
            window.location.reload();
          }
        }}>Reset</button>
      </header>
      <br />
      <section className="canvas-area">
        {/* {!doesCanvasHaveImg && <EventCardInstructions/>} */}
        <canvas id="c" />
        <CanvasParameters handleAddFormParameterToCanvas={handleAddFormParameterToCanvas}/>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};
```

```
const parameters = [
  {
    title: "name"
  },
  {
    title: "surname"
  },
  {
    title: "companyName"
  },
  {
    title: "email"
  }
];

const CanvasParameters = ({ handleAddFormParameterToCanvas }) => {
  return (
    <section className="section section-parameter">
      <h2 className="parameters-title">Parametreler</h2>
      {
        parameters.map(parameter => (
          <article className="single-parameter" key={parameter.title}>
            <button className="single-parameter__title" onClick={() => handleAddFormParameterToCanvas(parameter.title)}>
              {`{{${parameter.title}}}`}
            </button>
          </article>
        ))
      }
    </section>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following adjustments have resolved all my issues. It was a z-index issue. Make sure to initialize the canvas with **preserveObjectStacking: true** to establish a better control over what to send back and what to bring to front.

*If you encounter a problem pertaining to text objects disappearing on blur (focusing elsewhere (not outside of the canvas but say on image)) these adjustments solve that problem as well* => meaning that my text objects are always visible now.

```
  const handleAddFormParameterToCanvas = (formParameterText, visible = true) => {
    const textObj = new fabric.Text(formParameterText, {
      textBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      fill: '#000',
      visible
    });
    canvas.add(textObj);
    canvas.bringToFront(textObj);
    canvas.bringForward(textObj);
    canvas.setActiveObject(textObj);
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
```

```
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const initCanvas = () =>
      new fabric.Canvas("c", {
        height: 800,
        width: 800,
        preserveObjectStacking: true
      });
    setCanvas(initCanvas());
  }, []);
```